# Apache not showing index.html on address bar

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I would like to show my index.html file on address bar. When you go to http://www.example.com/ to redirect it to http://www.example.com/index.html and show that index.html on address bar.

**EDIT**

This is my .htaccess file. I have try neo example but with no luck.

```
DirectoryIndex  naslovnica.php
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* 404.html [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /naslovnica\.php
RewriteRule ^naslovnica\.php$ http://example.com/naslovnica.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Have you tried to do it yet?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to look into Apache `DocumentRoot` Directory. Have a look at the following Apache Docs...

[Apache DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot)

You will have to create the `index.html` and put it in the `DocumentRoot` directory.

From the DOCS...

`If your DocumentRoot "/usr/web" then an access to http://my.example.com/index.html refers to /usr/web/index.html`.

**Edited**
The following document explains about hiding the index. Guess you can use it to unhhide the index as well.

[Mod_Rewrite – Hide index.php](http://www.patricktaylor.com/mod_rewrite-hideindex)

The following might be a start towards finding the right solution...

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
# Redirect client requests for www.example.com/ to "www.example.com/index.html" in main doamin
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://www.example.com/index.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for replay. DocumentRoot Directory is setup correctly. I think the problem is DirectoryIndex directive.
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php. 
This means if you enter in address bar http://www.example.com it will show you contents of index.php or index.html file but it will NOT show filename on address bar. I don't know how to force apache to show filename.

Comment: I found [this](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-rewriterule-and-query-string/) which has some examples for `RewriteRule`. Hope this helps.